# Sql wont recognize or condition

Tags: sql, db2

Im having an issue with this query, it wont recognize the second OR condition and i cant recognize why.

```
select * 
from afip_inctascli 
WHERE UCASE(COALESCE(Cliente,'N')) = 'N' OR
UCASE(Cliente) = 'S' AND 
(TipoCta_Host IS NULL OR 
NroCuenta IS NULL OR
UCASE(RTRIM(COALESCE(Estado,'C'))) <> 'D' OR
UCASE(RTRIM(COALESCE(Estado,'C'))) <> 'A')
```

This specific `OR UCASE(RTRIM(COALESCE(Estado,'C'))) <> 'A')`

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that what you want is:

```
WHERE UCASE(COALESCE(Cliente, 'N')) IN ('S', 'N') AND
      (TipoCta_Host IS NULL OR
       NroCuenta IS NULL OR
       UCASE(RTRIM(COALESCE(Estado,'C'))) NOT IN ('A', 'D')
      )
```

I'm guessing the first two conditions are supposed to be one, followed by the second.

The second boolean expression has this logic:

```
   UCASE(RTRIM(COALESCE(Estado,'C'))) <> 'D' OR
   UCASE(RTRIM(COALESCE(Estado,'C'))) <> 'A'
```

This is trivially true.  If something happens to be equal to `'D'`, then it certainly is not equal to `'A'`.